# Passing ruby parameters using ajax

Tags: ruby, ajax

I have the following code which is sending the value of name when name = <%= "123124" %>, but it's failing when name = "any string".

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
            var name = <%= "hahaha" %> ;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/update/data",
                data: { 'name' : name}
            });
        });
```

What is the cause of that ?

Comment: Are you saying `name` equals the string `<%= "123124" %>` or name equals the string `123124`?

Comment: Yes, if name equals the string "123124" will work and if name equals "string", won't work

Comment: What exactly is failing? The application receiving the data? What error is it throwing?

Comment: It's not throwing any error. It's simply not sending anything when name = " any string".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is failing when there are spaces in the string because you need quotes around the value.  Use:

```
var name = '<%= "any string" %>';
```

Comment: "any string" has a space

Comment: The reason it was working with a number is that `var name = 123` is valid where `var name = abc` is not.

Comment: I still don't get why it's working. It was working with "123" but not with "abc". Aren't both of them strings written like that ?

Comment: Strings in Ruby yes.  Strings in javascript no.  `var name = <%= "hahaha" %>` will evaluate to `var name = hahaha`, which is why you need to wrap the whole erb block in quotes.

Comment: I have one more question: How can I pass a variable instead of #submit ? I've been trying  $("<%"#submit"%>") but it won't work.

Comment: Yes, it looks like you're just missing the =, that should be `$("<%= "#submit" %>")`